# Подстановка формулы f(x) в элементы интерфейса

Tags: python-3.x, gui, tkinter

Помогите плиз с заданием, немного полазил в инете и вышел такой интерфейс

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class Table(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, headings=tuple(), rows=tuple()):
        super().__init__(parent)

        table = ttk.Treeview(self, show="headings", selectmode="browse")
        table["columns"]=headings
        table["displaycolumns"]=headings

        for head in headings:
            table.heading(head, text=head, anchor=tk.CENTER)
            table.column(head, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        for row in rows:
            table.insert('', tk.END, values=tuple(row))

        scrolltable = tk.Scrollbar(self, command=table.yview)
        table.configure(yscrollcommand=scrolltable.set)
        scrolltable.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        table.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)


root = tk.Tk()
table = Table(root, headings=('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'), rows=((123, 456, 789, 444, 22), ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5')))
table.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```

в этой части показано как выглядит программа примерно, в хединге просто подсчет количества атрибутов, а в ровс первом идут задаваемые значения, ровс 2 должны быть ответы. В этом проблема, как написать функцию, что обсчитывает значение в первом ровс и выгружает их во второй. Обсчет неважно какой, подставьте для примера, формулу я описать могу.

```
table = Table(root, headings=('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'), rows=((123, 456, 789, 444, 22), ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос поставлен не ясно, как я понял надо брать данные из Rows 1 делать сними что-то и выводить в Rows 2. Вот примитивное решение.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class Table(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, headings=tuple(), rows=tuple()):
        super().__init__(parent)

        table = ttk.Treeview(self, show="headings", selectmode="browse")
        table["columns"]=headings
        table["displaycolumns"]=headings

        for head in headings:
            table.heading(head, text=head, anchor=tk.CENTER)
            table.column(head, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        for row in rows:
            table.insert('', tk.END, values=tuple(row))

        scrolltable = tk.Scrollbar(self, command=table.yview)
        table.configure(yscrollcommand=scrolltable.set)
        scrolltable.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        table.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)

rows=(123, 456, 789, 444, 22)

def count(rows):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(rows)):
        result.append(rows[i]/2)
    return result


root = tk.Tk()
table = Table(root, headings=('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'), rows = (rows,count(rows)))
table.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```

Либо так, либо сформулируйте вопрос понятнее.

Comment: все верно, брать числа и выводить их в резалт, проводя через формулу. формулу точно не помню но что то плана x*x и тд